# Adding a decal using multitexturing on an iPhone

Tags: iphone, opengl-es

I'm trying to overlay one image on top of another onto a simple quad. I set my bottom image as texture unit 0, and then my top image (which has a variable alpha) as texture unit 1. Unit 2 has mode `GL_DECAL`, which means the bottom texture should show up when the alpha is 0, and the top texture should show when the alpha is 1. But, only the top texture shows up and the bottom one doesn't appear at all. It's just white where the bottom texture should show through.

glGetError() doesn't report any problems. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

```
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, boxVertices);
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

glClientActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, boxTextureCoords);
glClientActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, boxTextureCoords);

glClientActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glClientActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

glClientActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, one.texture);
glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE);

glClientActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, two.texture);
glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_DECAL);

glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, 4);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using vertex arrays, you need to use [`glClientActiveTexture`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glClientActiveTexture.xml) instead of `glActiveTexture` when setting your texture coords.

Comment: Thanks...now my top texture shows up, but it's still not right. The bottom texture doesn't show at all (it's just white where the alpha of the top texture is 0). I'll edit my post with the new info.

Comment: Well... maybe you should read the doc for glClientActiveTexture and glActiveTexture ? the client one controls the vertex array setup (the client state), glActiveTexture controls the texture images. so switching all your calls to glClientActiveTexture was not the right thing to do (enabling/binding/texenv are still controlled by glActiveTexture)